# Where to store account/customer Data in a SPA for RESTful API (Gateway)?

Tags: angular, rest, api, single-page-application, microservices

We´re developing a SPA in Angular with a Microservice oriented architecture. Meaning there is an API gateway exposing an API to the SPA. Behind the API Gateway there a several microservices like a customer service. The API gateway is responsible also for authentication and acts as proxy for the underlying microservices at the moment. Authentication will be handled with Oauth and an encrypted Cookie.

Now consider the API gateway exposes an endpoint like /customers/{id}/orders to the SPA meaning the SPA has to know the customer id in this case. How do you handle the situations where you have to store customer/account specific data in a SPA/Browser to call a RESTful API (gateway)? Should the API gateway expose such an endpoint? Or better get the data from the authenticated user and the call then related microservice? Meaning to expose an endpoint like e.g. customers/orders? Without customer specific information.

I know there is LocalStorage etc. but it feels not good to store account/customer specific data in the browser.

Many thanks for the discussion and input.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if this is a customer site, you would return the customer at login. then the site would use that for other api calls. I wouldn't use local storage for this just keep it in your state. If the app is complex I would use ngrx: https://github.com/ngrx

If the app is used by someone that will see multiple customers data you would need a call to retrieve a list of customers. You would then use that ist of customers to build the links you need. Again I would just use state not local storage.